# Android. What is the best and safest way of storing data (updates from web service)

Tags: android, database, web-services, security

I saw similar questions but they don't fulfill my requirements.

I have an app that time to time needs to be updated from a web service. Data contains such fields as url, description, title. from 200k to 400k entries.
It is used locally and search among this data is performed quite often (depending on user's activity).

Data shouldn't be accessible by users and search needs to be as quick as possible. I know that there is no way to make it 100% unreadable, everything can be reverse-engineered and decrypted (I have to keep the encryption key on a phone). My goal is to make it as difficult as possible.

I have few choices:
 1. encrypt data on server and send it as binary file to phone. Decrypt it every when needed
 2. also send data as file. Read it, store to local database
 3. Get it as JSON (probably encrypted), store to database or file

There is an advantage of using JSON because it will be easier to implement updates of difference between local data and remote.

Also there is a question about databases. Should I store all entries encrypted and decrypt it every time I want to find something? It might affect phone's performance.

There is also one more possible layer of protection - make encryption keys dynamic. Get a key from server once a day, re-encrypt stored data, the next day key changes. However I suppose it is an overhead. Tell me if it isn't.

What option would you choose? Are there any better solutions?

P.S. database is going to be updated daily.

Thanks

Comment: 400k entries on a phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd store the data in SQLite, but also make the decryption scheme more intricate, using at least two keys... one, stored in the shared lib, other downloaded from the service and unlocked with that key.

This also plays into your thought up strategy - you can have one 'device' key, which comes with the APK - embedded as a hardcoded byte[] in the .SO, and another 'daily' key which will be used to open 'daily' data updates. Although, i'd rather be using the 'daily' key in a bytearray format, never saving it in any form on the device except having it decrypted in memory only for duration of it's use. This would be an upgrade to what I did, where i just saved that key as a base64-encoded devicekey-crypted string.

Working with SQLite is fairly easy, which you can see here - [Android Database to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415623/android-database-to-array/15415841#15415841).

I did something similar to what i'm explaining (without the updating daily keys however) here - [not decrypting what I crypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198228/not-decrypting-what-i-crypted).

Give it a look and discuss :)